# Unable to register broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect internet connectivity using broadcast receiver. I have registered broadcast receiver dynamically but when app launches it is showing error below:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.app.qrius.ConnectivityReceiver@3240fd8
```

I want to redirect to another activity which shows not network message when there is  no internet connection.

Below is my code:

**ConnectivityReceiver.java**

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(networkInfo != null){

        Toast.makeText(context,"On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
         Intent i = new Intent(context,Network.class);
         context.startActivity(i);
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  
  }

    @Override
protected void onResume() {

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
    super.onResume();
}

 private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo != null){

            Toast.makeText(context,"On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            //  Toast.makeText(context,"Off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context,Network.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((Activity)context).finish();
        }
    }
};

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add it to the AndroidManifest.xml

Similar to:

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".BatteryPowerBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Nope its not working and this method  is deprecated fro the apps target `android N` or above.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your activity as below for programmatically `register` and `unregister` broadcast receiver. You can use `LocalBroadcastManager` for this.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // Register to receive messages.
        // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive 
        //  Intents
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Unregister since the activity is paused.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    // Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
    // with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(networkInfo != null){

        Toast.makeText(context,"On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
         Intent i = new Intent(context,Network.class);
         context.startActivity(i);
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }
        }

    };

}
```

For more info, please [check](https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277)

Comment: So I need to register broadcast receiver in `onStart()` method rather than in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Yes. The think is that once the activity goes to stop, it will be unregister and it won't get register again if you are registering in onCreate() method. Oncreate works initial only

Comment: I have added broadcast receiver in `onStart()` method  but i am getting this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.app.qrius/com.app.qrius.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.app.qrius.ConnectivityReceiver@40901f0`

Comment: You can use LocalBroadcastManager. please check my code above

Comment: So shall I remove broadcast receiver class defined before.

Comment: yes. but copy the content and paste in this receiver

Comment: i have implemented ur code but when internet is off and I am launching app then its not redirect to another page as i have implemented intent to another page in Local Boradcast.

Comment: You should launch the app, and then on/off internet, your onReceive() will work. while launching the app, you can check internet is on/off then go to your page

Comment: its not working i have launched an app with internet on and when I am turnning internet off then its not redirecting to another screen.